# Imagemagick convert through Python

Tags: python, macos, operating-system, imagemagick

I have a bunch of PDFS that I'd like to convert to .tiffs using python.

```
data_path = " some path "
tiff path = " some path "
data_list = os.listdir(data_path)

for f in data_list:
   if (os.path.isfile(os.path.join(data_path, f)) and f.endswith(".pdf")):

      process = subprocess.Popen(
         ["convert", os.path.join(data_path, f), "-density 300", os.path.join(tiff_path, f+".tiff")],
         stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
         stderr = subprocess.PIPE
      )
      stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
      print("stdout", stdout)
      print("stderr", stderr)
```

The above works fine without the "-density 300". When I use that option (or any other), it throws the following error:

```
stdout b''
stderr b"convert: unrecognized option `-density 300' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1427.\n"
stdout b''
stderr b"convert: unrecognized option `-density 300' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1427.\n"
stdout b''
stderr b"convert: unrecognized option `-density 300' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1427.\n"
```

The command works fine on the terminal. Any help fixing it appreciated. Thanks in advance.

NOTE: I am on MacOS.

Comment: Did you try `...."-density", "300",...` ?

Comment: Thank you. That worked! I don't get it, I thought each option with it's value is supposed to be a string?

Comment: Don't know exactly why that helps, that's why I only commented and did not answer. Maybe [Popen constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) will shed some light on the matter.